# Cordova application with Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, cordova

I have an application that I wrote with Cordova. I recently added Swift functionality and Cocoapods functionality to it. I also use gym to automate the build.

The issue i'm facing is that when I try to get the code built with gym, it doesn't see my schema available (after running the hook for swift and cocopods installation). It only works if I open the workspace, "convert" to latest version in Swift, and then close the project. Problem is I need it automated.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm converting project to Swift using a modified version of the below:

https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support

and I'm using gym for building:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym

How can I convert to latest version of the *.pbxproj file in an automated way after cocoa pods? Can I do it via command line as opposed to converting it via opening Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I got the answer. The answer the builds were failing is because of schemas. The solution is to recreate the schemas for the project. You can do it in ruby:

First install the gem

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

Then use this script or a variation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'xcodeproj'
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("test.xcodeproj")
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```

After this the build works as expected.